# PHP SQL LEFT JOIN multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I have been playing around a bit and tried to find a solution but getting a bit stuck.

I have a 'meetings' table with 2 columns holding an id from 'members' which I need the members details to show on my meeting list.

I tried this, but it does not work...

```
$q = "SELECT (meetings.id) AS meetings_id, meetings.columnA, meetings.ColumnB, (members.id) AS members_id, members.first, members.last FROM meetings **LEFT JOIN members ON meetings.columnA = members.id AND meetings.columnB = members.id**";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { }
```

I can only get it to work if I only join on a single value, either 'columnA' or columnB', but this obviously only retrieved the data of for a single member.

Though this way works but is not ideal...

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM meetings";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { 
    $qm = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '$row[columnA]'";
    $rm = mysqli_query($dbc, $qm);
    while($rowm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rm)) {
        if  ($row['columnA'] == $rowm['id']) { echo $rowm['first']; }
    }
    $qm = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '$row[columnB]'";
    $rm = mysqli_query($dbc, $qm);
    while($rowm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rm)) { 
        if  ($row['columnB'] == $rowm['id']) { echo $rowm['first']; }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the JOIN to work or better way, so that I just need to make a single query?

Thanks.

Comment: OR instead of AND?

Comment: Try removing `, (members.id) AS members_id, members.first, members.last` from the `SELECT` section of your query. `LEFT JOIN` should already do this. Granted, in my experience, using a `JOIN` would add all of the columns of that table into the query results. I don't know how to filter the `JOIN` so that it doesn't select all of the columns.

Comment: @jarlh, Don't know why I didn't try that (brains gone fuzzy).  It works though it outputs 2 rows, each with the respective value showing and missing on each rows i.e. row1 - only showing member based on ColumnA and row2- only member based on columnB

Comment: I have tried using 'GROUP BY meeting.id' but will only show the first row which is missing the ColumnB member data

Comment: @Tiffany, can't remove my columns from the query as then it won't know what to look for. Additionally this is the way to call only the columns you want to use i.e. opposite of filter out.

Comment: `JOIN` with the `members` table will add that table onto the results. See http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-left-join/. Note that the examples provided don't include the `JOIN`ed table in the `SELECT` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want two `left join`s.

```
SELECT m.id AS meetings_id, m.columnA, m.ColumnB,
       me1.id AS members_id, me1.first, me1.last,
       me2.id AS members_id, me2.first, me2.last
FROM meetings m LEFT JOIN 
     members me1
     ON m.columnA = me1.id LEFT JOIN
     members me2
     ON me.columnB = me2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
SELECT 
meetings.id AS meetings_id, 
meetings.columnA, 
meetings.ColumnB, 
members.id AS members_id, 
CONCAT(m1.first,' ',m1.last) as  columnA_Member
CONCAT(m2.first,' ',m2.last) as  columnB_Member
FROM 
    meetings 
INNER JOIN 
    members as m1 ON meetings.columnA = m1.id
INNER JOIN 
    members as m2 ON meetings.columnB = m2.id
```

Comment: Tx. It works though it outputs 2 rows, each with the respective value showing and missing on each rows i.e. row1 - only showing member based on ColumnA and row2- only member based on columnB. I have tried using 'GROUP BY meeting.id' but will only show the first row which is missing the ColumnB member data

Comment: is both ColumnA & ColumnB has distinct member id? OR one column can has a member id ?

Comment: Both Column A and Column B has different members ids

Comment: If I show only the values of columnA and ColumnB, they show as they should, but if I do this...  if ($row["columnA"] == $row['members_id']) { echo $row["first"]; } and if ($row["columnB"] == $row['members_id']) { echo $row["first"]; }..... then this this then output separate rows

Comment: @JasonFI have updated my query, I think INNER JOIN best to use instead LEFT JOIN